# How do I share common functions and data across many activities in a single android application

Tags: android

I am looking for how to share functions and data across multiple activities within a single application.  I researched the daylights out of it and find some ideology war between overriding the extend for the application and doing a singleton, neither of which I can find examples sufficient to make me understand.  Basically I want to share data and share functions.  All activities need the same functions and data so this is not one activity sharing data with another activity.  It is all activities needing to have access to the same functions and data.

What I want to know is what is the way to go and how do I do it.  I need to see what I need to do in my 34 activities, what the class that is going to be common looks like, and what the Manifest entry needs to be.  I also need to be sure the common data area will not be closed by the OS.

This is my first Android - Java program and now find my 15,000 line, 34 activity application needs some structure.  I know, should have done things differently but the app works really well with two exceptions.  One is that it is structurally a mess.  Two is that the fact it is a mess is making it hard to fix one behavior I would like to fix.

This is a GPS based application for racing sailboats.  It is timing critical and every activity basically runs a once a second loop inside the location manager onLocationChanged function.  That part is fine and I do not want to put the GPS code in one place.  The problem is that most activities need to filter the data so a lot of code is copied and pasted to the activities.  The filter needs history so it needs to remember a state.  There are other functions that are used by several activities so these have been copied as well.  Think of a function that averages the last three GPS speed readings.  It needs to save some history, do its thing, and give a result. All activities need to do the exact same thing. All this works but the problem is that the averaging starts over every time I switch activities because every activity has its own filter.  That gives a glitch in the data that I need to get rid of.  I need common place to save the data and hopefully a common place to run the filtering and other functions that are common. If every activity can call the filter function that is using common state data, there will be no glitch across activity changes.

I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why you don't just make a Class with only static functions, passing needed Parameters? An example if you want to show an ErrorDialog

```
public class SharedHelper{

    public static Dialog showErrorDialog(Context ctx, String message, String title, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancelListener){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle(tilte);
        if (okListener != null){
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, okListener);
        }
        if (cancelListener != null){
           builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_negative, cancelListener);
        }
        return builder.show();
    }
}
```

Singletons are (from my point of view) one of the uglyest design pattern and will bite you sooner or later. Putting anything in `Application` requires you to cast it everytime to the Special Application class you designed. A class with only statics however is very flexible in its usage and doesn't need an instance to work.

Comment: This looks like it will work just fine.  This is just too easy!  Thank you so much.  I will mark it as the solution once I actually get the filter function in there. I tested it out a on a simple function and it seems to work.  I found reference that there is no Manifest entry needed and that seems to be true. I can pass parameters and get results back.  I called my class Helper and I called my test() function like this Helper.test(2);

Comment: seems legit :D. providing a BaseActivity as @bofrede suggest requires you to put any Activity inside the Manifest which is a hell when it comes to refactoring

Comment: Works great.  I have almost all the activities switched over.  Really easy.

Answer (score 4):

**For the storage-issue:**

lookup "SharedPreferences" & "SQLite" and decide afterwards which storage-type suits your needs more.

**For the methods-issue:**

This question is a bit more complex and there are different ways to do it. For example you could write a parent-class that implements all your globally needed questions and you let all your activity-classes inherit from it.

```
public class MyParentActivity extends Activity {
    public void myMethod() {
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Activity1of34 extends MyParentActivity {
    myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what this comes down to is not an Android problem but an Object-Oriented Programming problem. If I understand the situation correctly, I'm betting the best solution would be to take your shared filter and create a new Filter class that is instantiated within each Activity (this is likely more manageable than a singleton, but not having seen your use case, it's hard to say for sure). If you need to centrally track the averaging, you can simply create a static variable within the Filter class that maintains the same value during the life of the application. If you really want to maintain that average (even past the application's current lifecycle), you can persist it in a database or other local data options. However, I don't see any reason to put everything in a singleton just to maintain that average. Singletons (and all static data structures) can be potentially troublesome if used incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I, for one, do not mind the singleton pattern. Of course as everything else it should not be abused.

This is the construction I use for my shared objects. My app is divided into modules this way but can just as well be used in your case.

```
public class SharedDataObject {

    private Context context;

    private static SharedDataObject instance;

    public static SharedDataObject getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) throw new RuntimeException("Reference to SharedDataObject was null");
        return instance;
    }

    public static SharedDataObject createInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance != null) {
            return instance;
        }
        return instance = new SharedDataObject(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

     // notice the constructor is private
     private SharedDataObject(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
     }

    ...

    public void myMethod() {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

Notice that it uses the application context, that means among other things, means that the context owned by SharedDataObject cannot be used for GUI operations. But, the context will live for the entire lifetime of the application, which is nice.

Furthermore I hate having to pass a context everytime I wish to call methods on my SharedDataObject, thus I have a splashscreen calling SharedDataObject.createInstance() on all my modules.

Once an instance is create, I can call:

```
SharedDataObject.getInstance().myMethod();
```

Anywhere in my code, regardless of a context being present or not (from the place calling this code that is).

Comment: Uhh, long time ago I see an implementation like this. But its clearly misleading, as `createInstance` only really is creating if no instance is already present. It's also not ThreadSafe, so you could end up (like me) having multiple instances of your `Singleton`. This one was very hard to debug, as no one expects it like that. That was the last time I used Singletons.

Comment: @RafaelT Well, so far I have not encountered any problems using this method. If things starts acting strange, I will have a look at it. I cannot help to think how Thread Safety can be an issue if createInstance is only called when creating the instance, then getInstance throughout the rest of the app. Just as I described my usage by having a splashscreen.